# OpenCv for c++ on ubuntu is not getting installed

Tags: lubuntu, c++, libraries, opencv, linux-headers

Assalamualaikum

[I followed this article from top to bottom](http://www.codebind.com/cpp-tutorial/install-opencv-ubuntu-cpp/?fbclid=IwAR2h1Rqd-YNcyiILLzKr3MZMlC-tleX_6mp_a097KPWSRl5xY_DRGV_-DI4) But when I executed -

```
pkg-config --modversion opencv
```

an error message showed up -'Package opencv4 was not found in the pkg-config search path'

However, there exists a folder named opencv4 in -/usr/local/include.

(I want to convert my python image filter files into c++ image filters . I am using vscod and I din't find any extension for c++ there)

Comment: What OS & release are you using?

Comment: `pkg-config` doesn't care about `include/` directories - it looks for a `.pc` file somewhere like `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/`